# Using regex to replace file data

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, file-io

With some help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41902759/comparing-files-once-i-have-hostname/41907794?noredirect=1#comment71068443_41907794) , I have this working almost exactly the way I want. Now I need to be able to add the ability to remove data from a **file before the files are compared**.

The reason for this is the strings, "data", that i'm removing is known to differ each time the file is saved.

I have written a regex to select the exact text that I want to remove, but I am having trouble implementing it with my current code.

**Here are the three main functions**

```
HOSTNAME_RE = re.compile(r'hostname +(\S+)')
def get_file_info_from_lines(filename, file_lines):
    hostname = None
    a_hash = hashlib.sha1()
    for line in file_lines:
        a_hash.update(line.encode('utf-8'))
        match = HOSTNAME_RE.match(line)
        if match:
            hostname = match.group(1)
    return hostname, filename, a_hash.hexdigest()

def get_file_info(filename):
    if filename.endswith(('.cfg', '.startup', '.confg')):
        with open(filename, "r+") as in_file:
            #filename = re.sub(REMOVE_RE, subst, filename, 0, re.MULTILINE)
            return get_file_info_from_lines(filename, in_file.readlines())

def hostname_parse(directory):
    results = {}
    i = 0
    l = len(os.listdir(directory))
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        filename = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        sleep(0.001)
        i += 1
        progress_bar(i, l, prefix = 'Progress:', suffix = 'Complete', barLength = 50)
        info = get_file_info(filename)
        if info is not None:
            results[info[0]] = info
    return results
```

**This is the regex for finding the strings to be removed.**

```
REMOVE_RE = r"((?:\bCurrent configuration)(?:.*\n?){6})"
subst = ""
```

**EXAMPLE_FILE_BEFORE_DATA_REMOVED:**

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 45617 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 00:22:36 UTC Sun Jan 22 2017 by user
! NVRAM config last updated at 00:22:43 UTC Sun Jan 22 2017 by user
!
version 15.0
no service pad
!
no logging console
enable secret 5 ***encrypted password***
!
username admin privilege 15 password 7 ***encrypted password***
username sadmin privilege 15 secret 5 ***encrypted password***
aaa new-model
!
ip ftp username ***encrypted password***
ip ftp password 7 ***encrypted password***
ip ssh version 2
!
line con 0
 password 7 ***encrypted password***
 login authentication maint
line vty 0 4
 password 7 ***encrypted password***
 length 0
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 15
 password 7 ***encrypted password***
 transport input ssh
!
```

**EXAMPLE_FILE_AFTER_DATA_REMOVED:**

```
Building configuration...

!
no service pad
!
no logging console
enable 
!
username admin privilege 15 
username gisadmin privilege 15 
aaa new-model
!
ip ftp username cfgftp
ip ftp 
ip ssh version 2
!
line con 0

 login authentication maint
line vty 0 4

 length 0
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 15

 transport input ssh
!
```

I've tried doing something like #filename = re.sub(REMOVE_RE, subst, filename, 0, re.MULTILINE) within the get_file_info and get_file_info_from_lines but I'm obviously not implementing it correctly.

Any help would be appreciated as I am just learning.

**Running the Compare:**

```
results1 = hostname_parse('test1.txt')
results2 = hostname_parse('test2.txt')



for hostname, filename, filehash in results1.values():
    if hostname in results2:
        _, filename2, filehash2 = results2[hostname]
        if filehash != filehash2:
            print("%s has a change (%s, %s)" % (
                hostname, filehash, filehash2))
            print(filename)
            print(filename2)
            print()
```

I do not want to modify the current file. If all of this can be done in memory or a temporary file would be great.

**FULL CODE:**

```
import hashlib
import os
import re


HOSTNAME_RE = re.compile(r'hostname +(\S+)')
REMOVE_RE = re.compile(r"((?:\bCurrent configuration)(?:.*\n?){6})")


def get_file_info_from_lines(filename, file_lines):
    hostname = None
    a_hash = hashlib.sha1()
    for line in file_lines:
        #match = HOSTNAME_RE.match(line)
        if not re.match(REMOVE_RE, line):
            a_hash.update(line.encode('utf-8'))
        #=======================================================================
        # if match:
        #     hostname = match.group(1)
        #=======================================================================
    return hostname, filename, a_hash.hexdigest()

def get_file_info(filename):
    if filename.endswith(('.cfg', '.startup', '.confg')):
        with open(filename, "r+") as in_file:
            return get_file_info_from_lines(filename, in_file.readlines())

def hostname_parse(directory):
    results = {}
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        filename = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        info = get_file_info(filename)
        if info is not None:
            results[info[0]] = info
    return results


results1 = hostname_parse('test1') #Directory of test files
results2 = hostname_parse('test2') #Directory of test files 2



for hostname, filename, filehash in results1.values():
    if hostname in results2:
        _, filename2, filehash2 = results2[hostname]
        if filehash != filehash2:
            print("%s has a change (%s, %s)" % (
                hostname, filehash, filehash2))
            print(filename)
            print(filename2)
            print()
```

Comment: Any help? I'm still unable to get this to function correctly.

Comment: can you please add full code - so that we know which libs are used here? Cant get your code working! Sorry

Comment: @Md.SifatulIslam Done.

Comment: Can you verify that the diff between two files is only that one line? "diff file1 file2"

Comment: @velotron yes, the files are identical copies except for the part i've modified to verify that the block of text was actually being ignored.

Comment: The is an architrectural issue in you program.
And it does not allow you easily debug. Write functions that takes content string input an return the ouput. http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/slides/2014-07-pyohio/clean-architecture/

Comment: consider using difflib https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a way around the regex. I simply delete the lines by matching the line.

```
def get_file_info_from_lines(filename, file_lines):
    hostname = None
    a_hash = hashlib.sha1()
    for line in file_lines:
        if "! Last " in line:
            line = ''
        if "! NVRAM " in line:
            line = ''
        a_hash.update(line.encode('utf-8'))
        match = HOSTNAME_RE.match(line)
        if match:
            hostname = match.group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `get_file_info_from_lines`, simply ignore the line if it matches your regular expression. This way you don't need to actually modify the file or create another file, you simply calculate the hash with the lines that actually matter.

```
for line in file_lines:
    if not re.match(REMOVE_RE, line):
        a_hash.update(line.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: that does look like it should work but it's still saying there is a difference. The two files are identical except for the part where it says Current configuration. I just add or remove a few characters for testing.

Comment: I just ran a quick test in case I missed something but it's working OK. There must be something else wrong with your code.

Comment: well, my code is the same as above with just the change you made and it's still returning that the files are different. Did you change the lines in the Current configuration? Like change the "by user" to something else? Sun Jan 22 2017 by user1234 for example in one file but not the other?

Comment: Then also adding aditional text at the end of the file is another test.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i suggest you to use the following apporach :
Use a function to clean a line. The process lines to remove the empty ones.

Then use  [Difflib](https://pymotw.com/3/difflib/) to compare.
Use `python -m doctest file.py` to check  [doctest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html)

```
import re
source_content = """
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 45617 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 00:22:36 UTC Sun Jan 22 2017 by user
! NVRAM config last updated at 00:22:43 UTC Sun Jan 22 2017 by user
!
version 15.0
no service pad
!
no logging console
enable secret 5 ***encrypted password***
!
username admin privilege 15 password 7 ***encrypted password***
username sadmin privilege 15 secret 5 ***encrypted password***
aaa new-model
!
ip ftp username ***encrypted password***
ip ftp password 7 ***encrypted password***
ip ssh version 2
!
line con 0
 password 7 ***encrypted password***
 login authentication maint
line vty 0 4
 password 7 ***encrypted password***
 length 0
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 15
 password 7 ***encrypted password***
 transport input ssh
!
"""

target_content = """
Building configuration...

!
no service pad
!
no logging console
enable 
!
username admin privilege 15 
username gisadmin privilege 15 
aaa new-model
!
ip ftp username cfgftp
ip ftp 
ip ssh version 2
!
line con 0

 login authentication maint
line vty 0 4

 length 0
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 15

 transport input ssh
!
"""



HOSTNAME_RE = re.compile(r'hostname +(\S+)')
REMOVE_RE = re.compile(r"((?:\bCurrent configuration)(?:.*\n?){6})")


def process_line(line):
    """
    >>> process_line('! rgrg')
    '!'
    >>> process_line('username admin privilege 15 password 7 ***encrypted password***')

    """

    if line.startswith('!'):
        return '!'
    if HOSTNAME_RE.match(line):
        return match.group(1)
    if REMOVE_RE.match(line):
        return ''
    return line

#debug
for line in source_content.split('\n'):
    print(repr(process_line(line).strip()))

whitened = '\n'.join(process_line(line).strip() 
                     for line in source_content.split('\n'))

def clean_lines(lines, flag=''):
    """ Replaces multiple 'flag' lines by only one. 
    """
    res = []
    in_block = False
    for line in lines:

        if line.strip('\n') == flag:
            if not in_block:
                res.append(line)
                in_block = True
            continue
        in_block = False
        res.append(line)
    return res

print('^^^^^^^^^^^^^^')
no_exc = '\n'.join(clean_lines(whitened.split('\n'), flag='!'))
print(no_exc)
print('##############')
no_sp = '\n'.join(clean_lines(no_exc.split('\n')))        
print(no_sp)
```

Comment: This is the closest i've seen to actually removing the lines i don't want included. It looks like i might have to take the entire approach back to the drawing board.

Comment: No problem. You made beginner's mistakes in architerture. It happened to everyone.  Take a look at this video and example codes : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJtef410XaM I just applied what he advises :).