# RE.SUB not replacing data

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I've run into another complication with my program and found my old method to be non satisfactory, [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966568/using-regex-to-replace-file-data).

I have been able to get the REGEX for CRYPTO_RE to work now thanks to the help below. Now, however the get_hostname_from_file will not return the hostname. Issue with regex or how i'm looking at the lines?

**UPDATE**
The Code below now works. If anyone has a suggestion on a more efficient way or cleaner way to do this let me know. Still learning here! :)

**Full Code:**

```
import hashlib
import os
import re
import sys


# REGEX CONSTANTS
HOSTNAME_RE = re.compile(r'hostname +(\S+)')
REMOVE_RE = re.compile(r"((?:\bCurrent configuration)(?:.*\n?){6})")
#CRYPTO_RE = r'(?s)crypto pki certificate (.*)quit'
CRYPTO_RE = r"(?<=!\n)(crypto.*?quit)"
subst = ''

def hostname_parse(directory):
    results = {}
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        filename = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        info = get_file_info(filename)
        if info is not None:
            results[info[0]] = info
    return results

def get_file_info(filename):
    if filename.endswith(('.cfg', '.startup', '.confg')):
        with open(filename, "r") as in_file:
            return clean_file(filename, in_file.read())

def clean_file(filename, file_lines):
    file_lines = re.sub(CRYPTO_RE, subst, file_lines, flags=re.DOTALL)
    print file_lines
    return get_hostname_from_file(filename, file_lines)

def get_hostname_from_file(filename, file_lines):
    hostname = None
    match = HOSTNAME_RE.search(file_lines)
    if match:
        hostname = match.group(1)
    return hostname, filename, hash_file(file_lines)

def hash_file(file_lines):
    a_hash = hashlib.sha1()
    a_hash.update(file_lines.encode('utf-8'))
    return a_hash.hexdigest()


testpath1 = 'test1'
testpath2 = 'test2'

results1 = hostname_parse(testpath1)
results2 = hostname_parse(testpath2)

for hostname, filename, filehash in results1.values():
        if hostname in results2:
            _, filename2, filehash2 = results2[hostname]
            if filehash != filehash2:
                print ("%s has a change (%s, %s)" % (
                    hostname, filehash, filehash2))
                print(filename)
                print(filename2)
```

**Test File 1:**

```
!
hostname ROUTERORSWITCHNAME
!
crypto pki certificate chain **Censored***
 certificate self-signed 01
  3123445D 308201C6 A0030201 02020101 300D0609 2A864886 F70D0101 04050030 
  30312E30 2C060355 04031325 494F532D 53656C66 2D536967 6E65642D 43657274 
  69666963 6174652D 36363235 39393933 36301E17 0D393330 33303130 30303235 
  385A170D 32303031 11324564 30303030 5A303031 2E302C06 03550403 1325494F 
  532D5365 61265613 69676E65 642D4365 76472425 69636174 652D3636 32353939 
  39333630 819F300D 06092A86 4886F70D 01010105 0003818D 00308189 02818100 
  F4799A10 F1DB65EA FACC214B 88185DA2 133DBE2D B7DFFDB0 85DB1F87 FC111628
  quit
!
!
!
```

**Test File 2:** 
Direct copy of File 1 with come HEX digits changed.

**Desired Result:**

```
!
hostname ROUTERORSWITCHNAME
!

!
!
!
```

As you can see I need the entire block of HEX to be gone.

Comment: You are matching *each individual line* of a file, against a regex that's supposed to match multiple lines of hex data.  How could that possibly work?  ``.read()`` the whole file into a single string, and things might work better.  You'll also need to specify the DOTALL flag on that regex, as ``.`` does not normally match newlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like the following :

```
import re
regex = r"(?<=!\n)(crypto.*?quit)"
str = """!
hostname ROUTERORSWITCHNAME
!
crypto pki certificate chain **Censored***
 certificate self-signed 01
  3123445D 308201C6 A0030201 02020101 300D0609 2A864886 F70D0101 04050030 
  30312E30 2C060355 04031325 494F532D 53656C66 2D536967 6E65642D 43657274 
  69666963 6174652D 36363235 39393933 36301E17 0D393330 33303130 30303235 
  385A170D 32303031 11324564 30303030 5A303031 2E302C06 03550403 1325494F 
  532D5365 61265613 69676E65 642D4365 76472425 69636174 652D3636 32353939 
  39333630 819F300D 06092A86 4886F70D 01010105 0003818D 00308189 02818100 
  F4799A10 F1DB65EA FACC214B 88185DA2 133DBE2D B7DFFDB0 85DB1F87 FC111628
  quit
!
!
!"""
subst = ""
result = re.sub(regex, subst, str, 0, re.DOTALL)
if result:
    print (result)
```

**[DEMO](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMXzBjOFhqV3hKUWs)**

Comment: Yes, I can always get it to work that way while using the test data in a string like that. But I can't get it to work when reading in a file. I think @jasonharper is on the right track, however when changing to read i loose the ability to get the hostname out of the file.